# Could someone explain why this function doesn't always return the first element of the list

Tags: recursion

I have been having a look at some simple recursive functions to wrap my head around the concept. However one example has me a little confused.

The function below uses recursion to obtain the largest integer from a list:

```
A = [-4, 2, 4]
n = len(A)
def findMaxRec(A, n):
    if (n == 1):
        return A[0]
    else:
        return max(A[n - 1], findMaxRec(A, n - 1))
```

As n will eventually equal 1 why does the function not always return the first element in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases it might be helpful to just write out what code will be executed. I've tried to do that with your function as pseudo-code, where `n` is replaced with its value:

```
findMaxRec(A, 3):
    if (3 == 1):
        return A[0]
    else:
        return max(A[3 - 1], 
            findMaxRec(A, 2):
                if (2 == 1):
                    return A[0]
                else:
                    return max(A[2 - 1], 
                        findMaxRec(A, 1):
                            if (1 == 1):
                                return A[0]
                )
    )
```

Effectively, this results in:

```
max(A[2], max(A[1], A[0]))
```

Where the inner call `max(A[1], A[0])` = `max(2, -4)` = `2`

And the outer call `max(A[2], ...)` = `max(4, 2)` = `4`